# Cache issue with dynamically loaded div

Tags: jquery, ajax, jekyll

I have searched for a few hours and there are lots of competing ideas on the proper way to handle this going back many years and many jquery versions, so I'm not sure what the proper way is.

I have a responsive website, a handful of pages are loaded on the index into respective divs, and then hidden or displayed based on the user's clicks.

Within one, I need  second layer of responsiveness for 'blog' posts. This is a static site being migrated to jekyll.

I display a list of posts on this site's 'post' menu, and if a user clicks on one, I have a script within that 'post' template that modifies the div containing the list of posts, to the one that the user clicked on, like so...

```
---
html_id: posts
title: Posts
---

<div id="postdata">
{% for post in site.posts %}
<a class="postlink" href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a> - {{ 
post.date | date: "%d %B %Y" }}<br />
{% endfor %}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".postlink").on("click",function(event) {
  $(this).parent("div").load($(this).attr('href') + ' #postcontent');
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

The catch is the cache.  Once the div is changed if the user navigates back to where they were, they get the link that they clicked on rather than the list again, because the div has been changed.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Sounds likes something for `history.pushState`

Comment: That is interesting reading for sure, I wasn't aware of that method's existence.  Reading up and gonna give it a whirl, will post back after trying it out, thanks for the info.